# Calling Variables in a Formula in r

Tags: r, formula

I want to generalize my function in. I have defined `form = y~x`, and want to call y so that I use it within the function. y should be user (dynamic) defined and that is why I need a way to call it from the form. This is part of the code I tried and newdata is calculated within the function.

```
form = y ~ x
newdata = y
trial = function(form, x){
y = newdata
reg = lm(form, data = data.frame(x, newdata))
reg
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this out and it turned out to be what I needed

```
form = y ~ x
trial = function(form, x){
.
.
.
newdata = something
.
.
new.form <- as.formula(call("~", form[[2]], form[[3]]))
assign(deparse(form[[2]]), newdata)
reg = lm(new.form, data = data.frame(x, newdata))
reg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to work you could try :

```
form = y ~ x
newdata = 3*(1:100)+2
trial = function(f=form, x){
    y = newdata
    reg = lm(f, data = data.frame(x, y=newdata))
    reg
}

trial(x=1:100) # or trial(form,1:100)

Call:
lm(formula = f, data = data.frame(x, y = newdata))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          2            3  # as expected
```

The think is, in your previous function, the `form` was an argument and R did not understand that it was the `form` you defined. Using `f` with a default value of `form` solves this issue.

Was that what you wanted ?

Note that if you want to call the function and define `y` in the call you could do :

```
form = y ~ x
trial = function(f=form, x, y){
    reg = lm(f, data = data.frame(x, y))
    reg
}

trial(x=1:100,y=3*(1:100)+2)

Call:
lm(formula = f, data = data.frame(x, y))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          2            3
```

From what I understood from your comments this might be closer to what you expected :

```
form = y ~ x
trial = function(f=form, x, y){
    y = 5*y+2
    reg = lm(f, data = data.frame(x, y))
    reg
}

trial(x=1:100,y=3*(1:100))

Call:
lm(formula = f, data = data.frame(x, y))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          2           15
```

You call the function specifying `x` and giving a "first value" for `y`. Then, in the function, `y` is transformed (quite an easy transformation here) and then the regression is done.

Note that when you call the function, `y` is not the variable `y` but the argument in the function. If you have a variable `z` equal to `3*(1:100)` you can do `trial(x=1:100,y=z)`

Comment: This is not what I really wanted. I want a way to call any variable defined on the left side of ~, in this case y (but it can be any variable) and use it within the function by assigning it another value calculated within the function, in this case, newdata is calculated within the function and then I assign y=newdata.

Comment: ok. could you provide the code which creates `newdata` ? If I understand correctly newdata should depend from the variable you want in input (here it is y), otherwise the second way allow you to directly enter what you want for the variable at the left of `~`

Comment: This is the code which creates `newdata`.  `zvals <- round(qnorm(0.5 + 0.95/2), digits = 3)` ,  ` newdata <- zvals * x`. All these calculations are within the function and then y is assigned newdata. I agree I can as well directly define `form = newdata ~ x` but I think this would put much restriction on to the function.

Comment: but if `y=zvals*x` then `y=1.96*x` so the regression is quite obvious. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes but my problem is to find a general way to call y, say we could call it by `form[1]` and thus define `form[1]=1.96*x`

Comment: I don't think you can call `y` before it exists. You have to find what exactly is the regression you want. Do you know `x` before the regression ? And how should `y` be calculated ? Then, you call the function and specify x and y. Y can then be changed in the function (the part where I use `y=5*y+2`). Or you could also in your function call apply a value `z` to `y`.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm(weight ~ group)

form <- as.formula(y ~ x)

trial = function(form,y, x){
reg = lm(form, data = data.frame(x=x, y=y))
reg
}

trial(form,weight,group)
```

Comment: Not really, kindly go through the above conversation with etienne.